# Clicking a link that's nested inside a div using page-object gem

Tags: ruby, object, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I have a page that has a link `More restaurants`. I'm not sure how to access it using page-object gem by Cheezy.

When I click the link, it opens up a modal showing more restaurants than the ten in a list that it shows by default.

```
<div class="singleselect-radio-footer">
    <a href="" ng-click="toggleModal('singleselecRadioMoreOptionsModal.html')" r_test="singleselect-link-SelectRestaurant-more" ng-show="alwaysShowMoreLink || items.length > limit" class="ng-binding">More Restaurants</a>
</div>
```

I tried to use link

```
link(:more_restaurants, text: 'More Restaurants')

more_restaurants.click
```

and

```
div(:more_restaurants, class: 'singleselect-radio-footer')

def try_to_click
  sleep(2)
  self.more_restaurants_element.click
end
```

I'm wondering what the easiest way is to access such elements without an id.

Comment: What happens when you try these methods above?

Comment: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Anchor: located: false; {:name=>"content-frame", :tag_name=>"iframe"} --> {:value=>"search", :tag_name=>"a"}> to be located; Watir treated ["value"] as a non-HTML compliant attribute, ensure that was intended. I tried to add the frame and got this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the underlying methods for that link using Page Object gem you would need to add '_element' as a suffix to the name.

```
link(:more_restaurants, text: 'More Restaurants')
more_restaurants_element
```